# Julia pre-allocate array vs. MATLAB pre-allocate array

Tags: julia

In MATLAB, pre-allocation of arrays that would otherwise change size during iterations, is recommended. On the assumption the recommendation also ges for Julia, I would like to know how to do that.

In MATLAB, the following code pre-allocates a 5 by 10 array:

```
A = nan(5,10)
```

How would the same be obtained in Julia?

Answer (score 15):

`A = nan(5,10)` does not just allocate an array of `double`s, but also initializes the entries of the array with `NaN`s (although MATLAB may not really fill the array under the hood).

The short answer is `A = nan(5, 10)` in MATLAB is equivalent *in semantic* to `A = fill(NaN, 5, 10)` in Julia.

The long answer is that, you have many options and more control for array allocation and initialization in Julia.

### Array allocation *without* initialization

In Julia, it is possible to allocate an array or a matrix (which is a 2D array) and leave the entries uninitialized.

```
# Allocate an "uninitialized" m-by-n `Float64` (`double`) matrix
A = Array{Float64, 2}(undef, m, n)
# or equivalently
A = Matrix{Float64}(undef, m, n) # `Matrix{T}` is equivalent to `Array{T, 2}`
# you do not need to type dimensionality even with `Array`,
# the dimensionality will be inferred from the number of parameters
A = Array{Float64}(undef, m, n)

# You can do the same for arrays of different dimensions or other types
A = Array{Float64, 3}(undef, m, n, k) # 3D `Float64` array of size m*n*k
A = Array{Int64}(undef, m) # 1D `Int64` array
A = Vector{Float32}(undef, m) # 1D `Float32` (i.e. `single`) array. `Vector{T} === Array{T, 1}`
```

#### Array allocation without initialization using another array

In Julia, you can use the function `similar` to allocate an array using the type, element type and dimensionality information of another matrix and leave it uninitialized.

```
A = zeros(UInt8, m, n)
B = similar(A) # allocates the same type of array (dense, sparse, etc.) with the same element type, and the same dimensions as `A`

C = similar(A, Float64) # allocates the same type of array with the same dimensions as `A` but with the element type of `Float64`
```

#### Allocate an empty array

You can use the array construction syntax above passing `0` as the dimension, or simply `T[]` to create an empty array of type `T`.

```
A = Float64[]
```

### Array allocations *with* initialization

```
# Allocate a `Float64` array and fill it with 0s
A = zeros(m, n) # m-by-n Float64 matrix filled with zeros
A = zeros(m, n, k, l) # a 4D Float64 array filled with zeros

# similarly to fill with `Float64` 1s
A = ones(m, n)
A = ones(m) # a 1D array of size `m`
A = ones(m, 1) # an `m`-by-1 2D array

# you can use these functions with other types as well
A = zeros(Float32, m, n)
A = ones(UInt8, m, n, k)


# you can allocate an array/matrix and fill it with any value you like using `fill`
# the type is inferred by the value entered
A = fill(4.0, (m, n)) # m-by-n matrix filled with `4.0`
A = fill(0.50f, m, n, k) # a 3D Float32 array filled `0.5`s

# so to fill with `NaN`s you can use
A = fill(NaN, m, n)

# random initialization
A = rand(m, n) # m-by-n Float64 matrix with uniformly distributed values in `[0,1)`
A = rand(Float32, m) # an array of size `m` with uniformly distributed values in `[0,1)`

A = randn(m, n) # the same as `rand` but with normally distributed values

# you can initialize the array with values randomly (uniform) picked from a collection
A = rand([1, 5, 7], m, n) # values will be picked from the array `[1,5,7]`
```

You can use `fill!(A, value)` or simply use `A .= value` to fill an already allocated array with the same value. If you import the module `Random`, you may use `rand!` or `randn!` to fill an already allocated array with random values. This might give you significant performance benefits as allocations will be avoided.

You may take a look at [the Multi-dimensional Arrays](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/index.html) section of Julia documentation to learn more about arrays in Julia.

---

#### Notes

In Julia, you cannot change the size of a multi-dimensional (not 1D) *built-in* `Array`.

```
A = zeros(5,5)
A[6,5] = 2 # bounds error
```

But you can `push!` values into a *one-dimensional* `Array`. This will efficiently resize the array.

```
julia> A = Int[];
julia> push!(A, 1);
julia> push!(A, 2, 3);
julia> A
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
```

Comment: A really nice answer :).

Comment: Great list! Just an addition to allocating an empty array: there's also [`sizehint!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.sizehint!), which may improve performance if you know the end capacity from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

In MATLAB nan() allocates an array of NaN as floating point values. So in Julia

```
 A = fill(NaN, (5,10))
```

does this.